# Hermetian conjugates exercise

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

> Find the hermetian conjugates of the following matrices. Which of these is hermetian?
>
> $A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 + i & 4-7i \\ 3 + 2i & 7 \\ 4-18i & 6-3i \end{bmatrix}$
>
> $B = \begin{bmatrix} 1-5i & 1+2i \\ 1-2i & 1+5i \end{bmatrix}$
>
> $C = \begin{bmatrix} 1-7i & 4+3i & 2-8i \\ 4+6i & 1-6i & 8 + 4i \end{bmatrix}$

Here are my answers. Can someone please verify them?

$A^* = \begin{bmatrix} 1-i & 3-2i & 4+18i \\ 4+7i & 7 & 6+3i\end{bmatrix}$

$B^* = \begin{bmatrix} 1+5i & 1+2i \\ 1-2i & 1-5i \end{bmatrix}$

$C^* = \begin{bmatrix} 1+7i & 4-6i \\ 4-3i & 1+6i \\ 2+8i & 8-4i \end{bmatrix}$

None of these matrices is hermetian.

Comment: Right off the bat, you know that A,C are not Hermitian cause they aren't even square (A hermitian matrix is one whose hermitian conjugate is itself). To find the hermitian conjugate, you just transpose the matrix and then conjugate all of the entries.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with your answers and that none of the matrices is hermetian.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @MTurgeon Did you read the question??  This is [tag:solution-verification].